# Find maximum length of array where every entries are the same

Tags: python

Is the complexity of this code \$O(n^3)$? How can I improve the efficiency and reduce the complexity?

```
A = [3,2,4,2,4,2,4,5,3]
n= len(A)
def ALG2 (A,i,j):  #to check whether all entries between A[i] and A[j] are the same
    if i==j:
        return True     
    for k in range (i,j-1):
        if A[k] != A[k+1]:  
            return False
    return True

def  ALG1(A,n):   #find the max length of the arrays that are found in ALG2 
    l=0
    for i in range (0,n-1):
        for j in range (i+1,n-1):    
            if ALG2(A,i,j) and (j-i)>l:
                l= j-i

    return l

result = ALG1(A,n)



print (result)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this has a down vote :( Could you add a little more description on what this code is doing? If this is a programing challenge including the challenge description and a link would be all that's needed!

Comment: Yes, I believe if you have a loop in a function being called inside of a loop you must also add that as a nested loop.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/213544/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: It is not a challenge. It is my assignment actually . It is my first day to use stackexchange. really sorry for causing any inconvenience

Comment: What is the expected result for `A = [3,2,4,2,4,2,4,5,3]`?

Comment: reply to vnp:  it will be 1 If A = [2,2,2,2,2,4,3,2,2,2,5]  then result will be 5

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use better function names `ALG1` and `ALG2` don't really say what they're performing.
2. You should keep the creation of `A`, `n` and `result` at the bottom of your code.
3. You should keep your 'main' code in a main guard block:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       A = [3,2,4,2,4,2,4,5,3]
       n= len(A)
       result = ALG1(A,n)
       print(result)
   ```
4. You should follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), so that it's easier for others to read your code.
5. `ALG2` can be simplified by slicing the array from `i` to `j`, `A[i:j]`, and then checking if the set has a size of one.

   ```
   def ALG2(A, i, j):
       return len(set(a[i:j])) == 1
   ```
6. Your entire code can be drastically simplified by using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

   ```
   import itertools


   def ALG1(array):
       sizes = (
           sum(1 for _ in g)
           for _, g in itertools.groupby(array)
       )
       return max(sizes, default=0)
   ```

Comment: wow so is the itertools installed in python? and what is the itertools really for?

Comment: @WingHoLo Yes it's installed with Python. It's a collection of functions to help with iterators.

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm is indeed n^3, but you can do it in linear time. https://ideone.com/Ke3q5o

```
A = [3,2,5,4,4,4,4,2,4,4]

def findLongestContinuousSection(A):
    if len(A) == 0:
        return
    longestStart = 0
    longestStop = 0
    longestLength = 0
    longestVal = 0
    curStart = 0
    curStop = 0
    curLength = 1
    curVal = A[0]
    for k in range(1,len(A)-1):
        if curVal != A[k]: # record cur as longest
            longestVal = curVal
            longestStart = curStart
            longestStop = curStop
            longestLength = curLength
            curStart = k
            curStop = k
            curLength = 1
            curVal = A[k]
        else: # continue to build current streak
            curStop = k
            curLength += 1
    return (longestStart, longestStop, longestLength, longestVal)

print findLongestContinuousSection(A)
```

Comment: I'm confused where the Code Review is. Also this code looks needlessly long.

Comment: I only focused on the complexity.

Comment: so here we return 4 elements in a function. But it cannot be done in python or any programming at all right?